# Islamically when a women gets married does her primary responsibility go to her in-laws?

Tags: quran, hadith, nikah, women, family

Salaams, 
I was having a discussion the other night with my family as I am getting married soon. My father said that I will be "leaving this family" and joining another family and when I disagreed he said that my primary responsibility will be to my in-laws. I'm not sure where he got this from as I've been trying to find a hadeeth or ayat in the Quran that verifies this. Does anybody know if this is true and if so can they please share any references that I can look at? Any hadeeths or Quran verses that show how one should treat in-laws and whether or not the wife is responsible for them would also be much appeciated. 
Jazak'Allah.

Comment: No your primary responsibility go to your husband and your parents and your kids. Your in-laws especially the father of your husband and his brothers will remain a foreigner for you (from the perspective on dressing and 'awrah).

Comment: The father of the husband is a mahram.

Comment: The husband's parents are going to be elders and your relatives though marriage, so being considerate follows from basic etiquette. However the marriage contract itself does not make you 'responsible' for them in any way, rather you are entitled to demand separate accommodation.